# MysqlWorkbench - abas

Tags: mysql

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

OLa pessoal, tenho um pequeno problema. Na aba da esquerda, não aparece mais os bancos que foram criados. queria saber se alguem poderia me ajudr a restaurar essa janela.

Comment: Já tentou em `View`?

Comment: SIm, mas não tem a opção